# Perform segue depending on Click on a custom TableCellView sub item

Tags: ios, swift, nstablecellview

I have a custom UITableViewCell with some UILabel inside, my goal is to perform different segue if user tap on a UILabel or another one.
I could not understand on which sub item of my UITableViewCell user have just tapped on.
Is there a way to get on witch item of my UITableViewCell user tapped on and so perform the segue ??
Thank's a lot for any help.

Comment: Simply if you want to use Interface Builder Use Button instead of label and then connect segues and perform segue inside of IB action of Button

Answer (score 0):

1 ) Enable User interaction for the labels from storyboard ( attribute inspector ) or code using `userInteractionEnabled` and set value to true

2 ) In cellForRowAtIndexPath, add a target to these labels using `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPressOnLabel(_:)))

    myLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    myLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

3 ) create a function for this selector

```
@objc func didPressOnLabel(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Label tapped !!")
}
```